# creating manual view to In App purchase

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am using In App feature in my windows phone app and uploaded beta version to store. everything is working fine but it shows me two buttons, **Install** and **Cancel**, I need to change the text **install** to **Purchase**.

since we are not going to install anything we are purchasing an item so i need make fallowing changes like given Image

[image]

I don't know how to make these change, If any one have idea then suggest me what to do.

Thanks.

no answer at all. 
Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beta app, all IAP's are free - that's why in your first screen it is listed as "Free".

This purchase windows is common purchase experience defined by WP platform. You can't make changes/customizations to this. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), see point D.